# Calculating field after arcpy.Append_management()?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, append, field-mapping

[image]

I have some AutoCAD layers (f.e. Cad1, Cad2) and I want to export them into feature class in a geodatabase (f.e. feature_class). Also I want to calculate field in "feature_class" for objects from CAD.

I have Feature class "GISLayer" with "Name" field in my geodatabase. I want to add to this feature objects from CAD. And populate field "Name" in feature class with identical value "CAD_line" for all new features,that have been added from CAD

I use:

```py
arcpy.Append_management([Cad1,Cad2], feature_class, NO_TEST)
```

It's ok, but I have no idea, how to calculate the field for CAD objects using python.
Any idea?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. If you're looking to add a field on the fly and populate it during Append with constants based on the source, I suggest you convert the CAD drawing to singleton feature classes, add the column, populate the column, and *then* append.

Comment: Sorry for my English.I have Feature class "GISLayer" with "Name" field in my geodatabase. I want to add to this feature objects from CAD. And populate field "Name" in feature class with  identical value "CAD_line" for all new features,that have been added from CAD

Comment: @Vince, thank you very much, good idea )